# How to escape the regex when splitting an String array

Tags: java, regex, string, split, escaping

I'm looking for a simpler solution. I'm new to Java and I need a little help. I'm trying to split String to String[] by this '],['. The problem is that Java tries to get these like a Regex and I don't want to use it because I'm not good enough in it. I want just to split the string by these 3 characters "],[";
Here is my code:

```
String usefulData = ...;
String[] list = null;
String token = "],[";
list = usefulData.split(token);
```

And here is the error ouput: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 2
],[... Please, any suggestions how to make this think works?

PS. Is there any other way to split the String? I don't like this Regex very much. I have been used Qt and C# and in both places there is a way to escape from this Regular Expresions. Thanks a lot People!

Comment: I assume you're parsing something like [a],[b]? In this case the split out result would look like ["[a", "b]"]. Is this what you want?

Comment: @DonAngelo. Remember to accept one of the answers, by clicking the arrow besides each answer..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build your String using [`Pattern#quote`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) method.

That way you won't have to `escape` your special characters with a backslash. `Pattern.quote` makes all your `special characters` in string behave like String literal: -

```
String usefulData = "[a],[b],[c,d]";
String token = Pattern.quote("],[");
String[] list = usefulData.split(token);

for (String val: list) {
    System.out.println(val.replaceAll("\\[|\\]", ""));
}
```

**OUTPUT**: -

```
a
b
c,d
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, I've always escaped myself.

Comment: @LanguagesNamedAfterCofee Lol. :) Now you don't have to. Just `quote` yourself when needed ;)

Comment: @DonAngeloAnnoni.. Hello Don. You can try out my updated code. I have added code to remove `[` and `]` from start and end.

Comment: @DonAngeloAnnoni.. Using Regex for this kind of work is far better than using `substring`, `while` loop and all that stuff that is in the answer you marked.

Answer (score 5):

You want "\]\,\[".

```
String usefulData = ...;
String[] list = usefulData.split("\\],\\[");
```

This is because `[` and `]` are special characters in a RegEx. You have to escape them with `\\` to use them as regular characters.

Answer (score 2):

```
String usefulData = ...;
String[] list = null;
String token = "],[";
list = usefulData.split(java.util.regex.Pattern.quote(token));
```